# Send sms from Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, macos, sms, bluetooth

I want to make a simple program to send SMS from osX. I know there's already something available on the web, but I want to code it by myself. I need to know if there's any useful API to write this with Cocoa or how to send AT commands to any discovered device. Thank you.

Comment: So, to be clear: You want to talk directly to the user's phone via Bluetooth?

Comment: Yes. I just want to send SMSs connecting via Bluetooth and I want to create a simple GUI to do that easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search for "send sms cocoa" [swisssms](http://code.google.com/p/swisssms/). "SwissSMS is a Mac OS X front-end to SMS operators services." ... looks promising.

Comment: The questioner did not specify that he only wants to talk to iPhones; he said only that he wants to send SMS messages through a nearby phone via Bluetooth.

Comment: I was not talking about iOS. I just want to do that using a generic Bluetooth phone. For example, I can do that connecting to the device using "screen" and AT commands.

Comment: Looks promising but I specified I was looking for APIs or how to code a simple program. I want to code it. BTW, I will take at look at the source of the program.

Comment: Barring a simple, gift-wrapped API, an open source app that does what you're looking for is the next best thing.